# TypeScript: How to type object rest spread for any keys in function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, spread-syntax, typescript-types

I have a function that takes an object and returns an object. It returns the whole incoming object, but adds a key. The shape of the object is unknown, so it could have any keys, but it must have 2 certain keys.

```
const myFunction = ({
  num1,
  num2,
  ...rest
}: {
  num1: number;
  num2: number;
}) => ({
  num1,
  num2,
  sum: num1 + num2,
  ...rest,
});

myFunction({ num1: 4, num2: 3, foo: 'bar' });
// or myFunction({ num1: 4, num2: 3, baz: 'qux', quux: 'quuz' });
```

Here TypeScript yells about `foo`.

```
Argument of type '{ num1: number; num2: number; foo: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ num1: number; num2: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type '{ num1: number; num2: number; }
```

That was the simplified example.

Here is my actual function and how I tried to solve it using `extends`.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getSession } from 'utils/sessions';

const withAuthentication = async <
  T extends {
    request: NextApiRequest;
    response: NextApiResponse;
  },
  K extends T
>({
  request,
  response,
  ...rest
}: T): Promise<
  {
    userSession: {
      issuer: string;
      publicAddress: string;
      email: string;
    };
  } & K
> => {
  const userSession = await getSession(request);

  return { request, response, userSession, ...rest };
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

And the actual error is this.

```
Type '{ request: NextApiRequest; response: NextApiResponse<any>; userSession: any; } & Omit<T, "request" | "response">' is not assignable to type '{ userSession: { issuer: string; publicAddress: string; email: string; }; } & K'.
  Type '{ request: NextApiRequest; response: NextApiResponse<any>; userSession: any; } & Omit<T, "request" | "response">' is not assignable to type 'K'.
    '{ request: NextApiRequest; response: NextApiResponse<any>; userSession: any; } & Omit<T, "request" | "response">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ request: NextApiRequest; response: NextApiResponse<any>; }'.
```

How can you type such a function?

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea; `{ num1: number; num2: number; } & any` as the argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring with the rest parameter makes it tricky to get this to typecheck, but if you just spread the argument object and add the `userSession` property, you end up with a fairly readable solution:

```
const withAuthentication = async <
  T extends {
    request: NextApiRequest;
    response: NextApiResponse;
  }
>(arg: T): Promise<{
    userSession: {
      issuer: string;
      publicAddress: string;
      email: string;
    };
  } & T> => {
  const userSession = await getSession(arg.request);
  return { ...arg, userSession };
};
```

([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQB5gIIAdgBKEAjgK4QDOYyA3gL4BQoksiK6WehluA9iBRT0m4aPCTIAqoKgBlShWD9aDZMmAUK5KAC5kVKKADmAblXJcpAEYAbYAmwATR1AV6Dxs2ogBbOMBt3MEMQUwZGGwhqIyj5TSUQPQAKVzJKMD0OHHwiNKoASmQAXgA%20ZAAFKF4fDQgAHmloOMV%20EoYGBH4qZAB3YDAAC2xSQYhwezgwBOLkOAoATxAEZDrzABVkTEgQRwoVNTVU8ipMra5c47AvA9cKPgEIU84cni6Ia8YSpLgoIz01-J6SrVWp1GjmNSkGTNBJ6cEHA4aLTQIIhMIItSWWz2JwuNz6YKeCEHXz%20QIEtHXNR0D7IABkyDWZVK%202QnQE1ChTQU0yKsx6-misR5-G%20vwAdEd0vlrq4wKQoCBaMhxaqfkYADTILlyEVKmnhMwdLrUSDdPlzRbLJKFFnwtkm5C3GZwAX9Xr9IYjAZjKYISYJJI0KUnWh0LW3e6COHhzZYKBwPQAFjo%20XCQA))

Answer (score 3):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Demo: https://repl.it/@chvolkmann/InternalFrugalCopyleft

```js
interface MyArgs {
  a: number
  b: number
}

const doSomething = <A extends MyArgs>(args: A) => ({
  ...args,
  sum: args.a + args.b
})

console.log(doSomething({ a: 10, b: 5, foo: 'bar' }))
// Output:
// { a: 10, b: 5, foo: 'bar', sum: 15 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles, too, but I don't know if its the best approach.

```
import { UserSession } from 'features/user-authentication/types';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getSession } from 'utils/sessions';

const withAuthentication = async <
  T extends {
    request: NextApiRequest;
    response: NextApiResponse;
  }
>({
  request,
  response,
  ...rest
}: T): Promise<
  {
    request: NextApiRequest;
    response: NextApiResponse;
    userSession: UserSession;
  } & Omit<T, 'request' | 'response'>
> => {
  const userSession = await getSession(request);

  if (userSession) {
    return { request, response, userSession, ...rest };
  }

  throw new Error('Unauthenticated');
};

export default withAuthentication;
```